# SQL Query, Sort on Two Substrings

Tags: mysql, sorting, substring

I am looking to sort everything in a column based upon the 2nd number and then the 3rd number.

For example:

1.197.980 is greater than
1.191.5061

The current SQL query that I currently have is the following.

```
SELECT av_sig_ver
,CONVERT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(av_sig_ver,'.',-2),UNSIGNED INTEGER) AS 'av_sig_ver'
FROM `test`.`test_fep_signatures`
ORDER BY av_sig_ver DESC
LIMIT 50;
```

I get the following output.

```
+--------------+------------+
| av_sig_ver   | av_sig_ver |
+--------------+------------+
| 1.191.5061.0 |       5061 |
| 1.191.5061.0 |       5061 |
| 1.191.5061.0 |       5061 |
| 1.191.5061.0 |       5061 |
| 1.191.5015.0 |       5015 |
| 1.191.5015.0 |       5015 |
| 1.191.4993.0 |       4993 |
| 1.191.4993.0 |       4993 |
| 1.191.4960.0 |       4960 |
| 1.191.4710.0 |       4710 |
| 1.191.4634.0 |       4634 |
| 1.191.4634.0 |       4634 |
| 1.191.4634.0 |       4634 |
| 1.191.4588.0 |       4588 |
| 1.195.3814.0 |       3814 |
| 1.195.3814.0 |       3814 |
| 1.195.3814.0 |       3814 |
| 1.195.3814.0 |       3814 |
| 1.195.3814.0 |       3814 |
| 1.195.3814.0 |       3814 |
| 1.195.3814.0 |       3814 |
| 1.195.3814.0 |       3814 |
| 1.195.3797.0 |       3797 |
| 1.195.3797.0 |       3797 |
| 1.195.3797.0 |       3797 |
| 1.195.3764.0 |       3764 |
| 1.195.3764.0 |       3764 |
| 1.195.3764.0 |       3764 |
| 1.195.3764.0 |       3764 |
| 1.195.3741.0 |       3741 |
| 1.195.3711.0 |       3711 |
| 1.195.3623.0 |       3623 |
| 1.195.3600.0 |       3600 |
| 1.195.3600.0 |       3600 |
| 1.195.3600.0 |       3600 |
| 1.195.3600.0 |       3600 |
| 1.195.3510.0 |       3510 |
| 1.193.3509.0 |       3509 |
| 1.193.3509.0 |       3509 |
| 1.193.3509.0 |       3509 |
| 1.193.3509.0 |       3509 |
| 1.193.3509.0 |       3509 |
| 1.193.3485.0 |       3485 |
| 1.193.3485.0 |       3485 |
| 1.195.3480.0 |       3480 |
| 1.195.3480.0 |       3480 |
| 1.191.3480.0 |       3480 |
| 1.195.3480.0 |       3480 |
| 1.195.3480.0 |       3480 |
| 1.195.3480.0 |       3480 |
+--------------+------------+
50 rows in set, 11160 warnings (0.01 sec)
```

So I pretty much want to sort by the number after the 1st "." and then sort after the 2nd period ".".  I want the four digit to be higher than the three digit.  I hope this all makes sense. :)

So I should have the following:

```
1.197.XXXX
1.197.XXX
1.195.XXXX
1.195.XXX
1.193.XXXX
1.193.XXX
1.191.XXXX
1.191.XXX
```

EDIT: SOLVED
Thanks for the suggestions.  Got me thinking in the right direction.  This was my fix for it. :)

```
SELECT av_sig_ver
,CONVERT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(av_sig_ver,'.',-2),UNSIGNED INTEGER) AS 'one_av_sig_ver'
,CONVERT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(av_sig_ver,'.',-3),UNSIGNED INTEGER) AS 'two_av_sig_ver'
,COUNT(NULLIF(TRIM(av_sig_ver), '')) AS 'total'
FROM `test`.`test_fep_signatures`
GROUP by av_sig_ver
ORDER BY two_av_sig_ver DESC, one_av_sig_ver DESC;
```

Comment: `order by` can accept arbitrary expressions. `order by string_operation_to_get_your_third_number_component(fieldname)`

Comment: By also naming the converted `av_sig_ver` a different alias than, `av_sig_ver` (ie, `conv_av_sig_ver`) that can be referenced within your `ORDER BY`.

Comment: If you have solved your problem, you can answer your own question and in two days accept the answer so that future readers will know what the solution was. The way it is now, it looks like this question is still unsolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT av_sig_ver
,CONVERT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(av_sig_ver,'.',-2),UNSIGNED INTEGER) AS 'one_av_sig_ver'
,CONVERT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(av_sig_ver,'.',-3),UNSIGNED INTEGER) AS 'two_av_sig_ver'
,COUNT(NULLIF(TRIM(av_sig_ver), '')) AS 'total'
FROM `test`.`test_fep_signatures`
GROUP by av_sig_ver
ORDER BY two_av_sig_ver DESC, one_av_sig_ver DESC;
```